# how to reshape a matrix to 3D but I found that matlab will do this according to column

Tags: python, numpy, matlab

I was trying to transform a python program to matlab and I found that the transpose function cannot be realized in matlab. In python it goes as the first picture. But in Matlab, I found it read by column, which is so different from python. And I use cat and reshape function in Matlab, I cannot find one way to realize the same function as in python. [enter image description here][1]

For example, I create a matrix in matlab, and reshape it. But I found it do not read in rows.

```
a = [1:1:100];
b = reshape(a,2,5,10);
```

I hope it can be divided by its rows rather than columns.
And the codes for python is

```
a = np.linspace(0,10*10-1,10*10)
b = a.reshape(10,10)
c = np.transpose(b[0::2],b[1::2],axes=(1,0,2))
```

So I wonder if there is anyways that I can get a results like c in python?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc4Er.jpg

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your python code doesn't work. Should the last line be `c = np.transpose((b[0::2],b[1::2]),axes=(1,0,2))`?

Comment: oh, sorry about the typo

Answer (score 0):

To have the same shape (in the sense that the same tuple of indices would access the same elements) you should use:

```matlab
a = 0:1:99;  % Note that your python code goes from 0 to 99, not from 1 to 100
b = reshape(a, 10, 10);
b = b';  % This puts b in a similar order as numpy would use, so it becomes easier to use;
c = permute(cat(3, b(1:2:end,:), b(2:2:end, :)), [1, 3, 2]);  % Equivalent to numpy transpose of the concatenated array on your python code

% Note that the way Matlab displays the matrices is different, but the indices are matching:
assert(c(1,1,1) == 0)
assert(c(1,1,2) == 1)
assert(c(1,2,1) == 10)
assert(c(1,2,2) == 11)
assert(c(2,2,2) == 31)
```